# jQuery UI "CHOSEN" Plugin: remove option on select list don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select-options

I have a server-side generated list of options like the following,

```
<select id="chosen">
    <option value="1">select 1</option>
    <option value="2">select 1</option>
    <option value="3">select 1</option>
    <option value="4">select 1</option>
    <option value="5">select 1</option>
</select>
```

based on the option selected, the data will be pulled from the server and append to a table (row)

What I want to achieve is, when I select the item from the list of options (using onChange) I want to remove that selected item from the list (so that I do not repeat selecting the same item again by mistake)

I have compiled the following onChange script

```
    $("#chosen").change(function() {

        var data = "";
        var val = $("#chosen option:selected").val();           

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url : "pull_cust_inv.php",
            data : "invId="+$( "#chosen option:selected" ).val(),
            async: false,
            success : function(data) {
                $("#inv_list").append(data);
                //$("#chosen option:selected").remove();
            },
            error: function() {

                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });

        // REMOVE SELECTED OPTION
        $("#chosen option[value="+val+"]").remove();
    });
```

However, for some weird reason, the option still appears in the list (does not remove itself) but when I select it for the second time it does not get selected.

can someone advise what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer myself.
I am using the "chosen" jquery plugin for the select dropdown list, therefore the traditional method (below) will not work

```
$("#chosen option[value="+val+"]").remove();
```

**Solution**
if anyone happens to use the technique i've implemented using the "chosen" (jquery Plugin) the correct way to remove a selected option is to write the following lines.

```
$("#chosen option[value="+val+"]").remove();
$("#chosen").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

what is means is, once your "remove" the option element you will have to trigger the "chosen:updated" method.

This only implies if you are using the chosen Jquery UI plugin.

Hope it helps someone
:)

Answer (score 0):

Your Missing `''` on your remove

Try Replacing

> `$("#chosen option[value="+val+"]").remove();`

with

> `$("#chosen option[value='"+val+"']").remove();`

Comment: I did try it, infact i made it a string like $("#chosen option[value='10002']").remove(); but the result seem to be the same...